# Should a new thread be created each time in web workers? (React)

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, react-hooks, web-worker

has anyone worked with web workers in react?

i just want to know if i am on the right path.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useWorker(workerPath, autostart = false) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const worker = new Worker(workerPath);

    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      if (event.data === 'start') {
        console.log('Worker started');
      } else {
        setData(event.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (autostart) {
      worker.postMessage('start');
    }

    return () => {
      worker.terminate();
    };
  }, [workerPath, autostart]);

  const startWorker = () => {
    const worker = new Worker(workerPath);

    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      if (event.data === 'start') {
        console.log('Worker started');
      } else {
        setData(event.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    worker.postMessage('start');
  };

  return [data, isLoading, startWorker];
}

export default useWorker;
```

```
import useWorker from './hooks/useWorker';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [autostart, setAutostart] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [data, isLoading, startWorker] = useWorker('worker.js', autostart);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={startWorker}>Start Worker</button>
      <label>
        Autostart:
        <input type="checkbox" checked={autostart} onChange={(e) => setAutostart(e.target.checked)} />
      </label>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Worker result: {data}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
//worker
onmessage = (event) => {
  postMessage(event.data)

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => postMessage(JSON.stringify(json)))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Should a new worker be created every time i fire a request that requires a worker? should it be terminated somehow afterwards?

[image]

Comment: **No.** Generally, the "worker" paradigm is that a consistent number of "workers" remain alive, servicing the incoming requests, regardless of how many requests might  be incoming. That's the point of having a "worker" pool. Your local McDonald's restaurant does not hire an additional employee every time someone new walks into the door, wanting to buy a sandwich.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Gotcha, adding worker.terminate(); after the post.message kills the job